# How to build a pie chart based on int values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pie-chart

I have some int variables and I need to create a pie chart based on them in a visual studio form.
How do I link them together as I seem to only be able to find how to link it to a database, which is too cool for me.

Comment: with "form" do you mean windows forms? Or are you using WPF?

Comment: Place a Chart Control on the form and set it to show a Pie charttype! The Chart is in the Data panel of the toolbox. Also add the namespace `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;` for easier access of the properties! You simply add the ints as the values in a series.points.add call..

Comment: Yeah, I added the chart already but can you elaborate on the values in a series.points... as I lost you there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a code-example how you could create a pie chart. I hope this helps:

```
private void DrawPieChart(int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4, int value5)
{
    //reset your chart series and legends
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Legends.Clear();

    //Add a new Legend(if needed) and do some formating
    chart1.Legends.Add("MyLegend");
    chart1.Legends[0].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;
    chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
    chart1.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    chart1.Legends[0].Title = "MyTitle";
    chart1.Legends[0].BorderColor = Color.Black;

    //Add a new chart-series
    string seriesname = "MySeriesName";
    chart1.Series.Add(seriesname);
    //set the chart-type to "Pie"
    chart1.Series[seriesname].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

    //Add some datapoints so the series. in this case you can pass the values to this method
    chart1.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY("MyPointName", value1);
    chart1.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY("MyPointName1", value2);
    chart1.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY("MyPointName2", value3);
    chart1.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY("MyPointName3", value4);
    chart1.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY("MyPointName4", value5);
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding `chart1.SaveImage("sample.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)` at the end. But the *sample.png* file is just blank white screen, can someone please correct why?